# Pandas dataframe conditional statement didn't give me what i expected

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lbl = [0, 1, 2, 3]
lbl2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

label = lbl + lbl2

df = pd.DataFrame({"label":label})

#matching lbl and lbl2
pairs =[]
for i in range(3):
    pair = (i,i+1)
    pairs.append(pair)
```

when I hit this on terminal

```
(df.loc[:,'label'][df.index > (num_old_lbl - 1)]) & (df['label'] == pairs[0][1])
```

I got what I expected like this
[image]

```
(df.loc[:,'label'][df.index > (num_old_lbl - 1)]) & (df['label'] == pairs[1][1])
```

but when I changed the line like this, every values show False.  I expected row 6 will be True.

Comment: what is num_old_lbl? And also what are you trying to achieve with your conditional statements?

Comment: Oh i missed it it' just nuber three. num_old_lbl = 3

Answer (score 1):

We get the expected result using this writing (setting up `num_old_lbl` to 3) :

```py
>>> (df.index > (num_old_lbl - 1)) & (df['label'] == pairs[1][1])
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: label, dtype: bool
```

It also works as expected with the given example :

```py
>>> (df.index > (num_old_lbl - 1)) & (df['label'] == pairs[0][1])
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
8    False
9    False
Name: label, dtype: bool
```